# How are different internet explorer 8 sessions recognised?

Tags: http, cookies, internet-explorer-8

With session I mean a period from opening IE8 to closing IE8.

The secure mode of IE8, which is enabled by default, seems not to like cookie use between sessions sometimes (When using SSL I think). It leads to 'cookie not recognised' at our site. I saw at another site that they throw away (?) data after a session, i.e. data is reset next time IE8 is started. I can't seem to find though how to distinguish between IE8 sessions.. Anyone can help maybe? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identifer IE sessions, especially from the server side.  Cookies that do not have an explicit expiration date assigned to them by the webserver are known as "session" cookies are are supposed to be thrown away by IE (or any other browser) when closed.